# Install CherryPy on Linux hosting provider without command line access

Tags: python, linux, cherrypy

I have a linux based web hosting provider (fatcow.com) that doesn't give any command line access and won't run the setup script for CherryPy (python web server) for me.

Is there any way to run get around this limitation so that I have a working install of CherryPy?

This might be more or a serverfault.com question, but maybe someone here has dealt with this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CherryPy is pure Python, then you may be able to simply put the `cherrypy` folder in the same place your project resides. This will enable you to `import` the necessary things from CherryPy without needing to copy it to the official install directory. I've personally never used CherryPy, so I don't know precisely what's being installed and how it's used, but I've done this same thing with Django without a hitch.

OK, I just downloaded CherryPy 3.1.2, unzipped it, and copied the contents of `./cherrypy/tutorial` to `.`, ran the [suggested](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyInstall) tut101_helloworld.py and it seems to work.

As far as hooking it up to Apache, it depends on what's available on your host. I think the most common Python interface is [`mod_python`](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModPython). When following these instructions, it's important to set the `sys.path` right in order for `mod_python` to be able to see `cherrypy`.

Comment: I just stumbled across this and thought I'd mention that mod_python is (or is becoming) deprecated in favor of mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to mod_python is mod_wsgi - http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithCherryPy

But as Kyle mentioned, youll need to be able to edit your apache conf.